# app.use(express.json()) giving an unexpected token error

Tags: json, express

I have simplified my code to strip away everything but the error. The code works fine on my server but produces an `unexpected token` error in the local environment.

This code works:

```
const express = require("express");
app = express();

const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

This code gives the error:

```
const express = require("express");
app = express();
app.use(express.json());

const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

I am using postman for testing. The full error is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
 in JSON at position 46
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at JSON.parse (&lt;anonymous&gt;)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at parse (C:\WebDev\MongoDB\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:89:19)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\WebDev\MongoDB\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at invokeCallback (C:\WebDev\MongoDB\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at done (C:\WebDev\MongoDB\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\WebDev\MongoDB\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:182:13)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1094:12)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
        </pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Weird right! Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## i guess you are using express version > 4.1

this should solve ur problem.

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```